# Where to learn the latest standardised Java

Tags: java, c, standards

Recently i had been wondering [ since i am about to learn it ], where can i find the latest International Standard of Java?

( Just like we have C and C++ standards)

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have an (ISO) International Standard.

The latest drafts for the Java specification are at [JSR 901](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=901) (Java Language Specification) and [JSR 924](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=924) (Java Virtual Machine Specification).

Answer (score 1):

As Acme says, there is no International Standard. The language definition is published directly by Sun/Oracle: The [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C, Java doesn't really have different flavours that would require a standardization process. There are different versions of the JVM (Sun, OpenJDK, Mac OS...) which may do things differently internally but there are no differences in terms of instructions and syntax. You can check the Java Language Specification and the JSRs to document yourself on the language.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C and C++ which are standardized by "independent" standards organizations Java is governed by the Java Community Process which is headed by Oracle. This group of organizations (companies like SAP, IBM, ... are involved) works based on "JSR" (JAVA Standard Request) documents which get approved. These JSRs can be found on http://jcp.org/

Interesting starting points might be [JSR 336: JavaTM SE 7 Release Contents](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336), which points to further JSRs ...